# Code completion similar to IntelliJ for Python

Tags: python, intellij-idea, autocomplete, ide, autocorrect

I recently started working with Java and I really like to auto-correction / completion features in IntelliJ.

Does something similar exist and is as powerful for Python?

Comment: You can try to install [Python](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/plugin-overview.html) plugin from JetBrains marketplace into IntelliJ IDEA. (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html)

Comment: Would it make any difference (about my request) to PyCharm?

Comment: This is better suited for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using JetBrains' IDE, so you could try out their [PyCharm for Python](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). It's from the same company so I presume that PyCharm's autocomplete features are on par with that of IntelliJ.

As I never used IntelliJ, the recommendations below are based on the autocomplete features of PyCharm.

I was using [Tabnine](https://www.tabnine.com/) on [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) and it does support many IDEs. However, I stopped using it now since it is using too many resources on my laptop and I feel that auto complete is kind of distracting (but that is just my opinion). You could also try [GitHub's Copilot](https://github.com/features/copilot), my friend uses it but for reasons mentioned earlier, I didn't try it. These two however, may not be the autocompletes you are looking for as they can basically write your code for you.

Comment: It's actually more than code auto-complete: it is underlining in red any mistake that would make the code not compile in real time, suggest package import lines directly when using methods that require it, it greys methods and variables name when they are not used anywhere else in the code, it recognize full section of the code that could be simplified and you can make the transformation in one click, etc ... with all that I almost don't need any debugging ! (also there is a single shortcut that restructure all the typo of the code in a nice way, with standart indendations, spaces, etc..)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, PyCharm does have code autocorrection as well but the other two (tabnine and copilot) does not. In that case, I would suggest using PyCharm

Comment: Trying PyCharm right now, just starting but so far it seems to do what I'm looking for.